# Are elements of different invariant subspaces of a self-adjoint set orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, group-theory, mathematics

I know that self-adjoint operators have orthogonal eigenspaces, but how does that generalize to the orthogonality of invariant subsapces?

I am reading Fonda's *Symmetry Principles in Quantum Physics* right now and, early on (page 8), he uses that if a set of self-adjoint operators (representing observables) $S$ is reducible, then

1. not only does there exist an invariant subspace (as per the definition of reducible), but in fact the underlying vector space is *completely reducible* and
2. the various invariant subspaces are orthogonal.

How does one prove these facts? I have one more related question:

3. I am not sure to what extent these facts fall under the purview of group theory, given that the set of self-adjoint operators is not a subset of $GL(V)$ (and so these operators cannot be the image of some representation). Is there any connection to group theory here given mentions of *irreducible* etc.?

Comment: How does the author define reducible and completely reducible?

Comment: These are words that I am using to simplify the more long-winded explanations there. Here I mean them in their group theoretic senses (reducible = exists an invariant subspace, completely reducible = exists a decomposition of the whole space into various invariant/irreducible subspaces). @TobiasFünke

Comment: The author only uses *irreducible* though. Ballentine does this too, even though I can't see the connection to group theory. @TobiasFünke

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but if you want a mathematical proof, you need precise meaning and definitions, though...

Comment: Let me know if this works. Reducible = there exists an invariant subspace (invariant under each element of $S$) while completely reducible = there exists a suitable basis such that each operator in $S$ is block diagonal. @TobiasFünke